# How to get the last amount paid grouped by city and year?

Tags: sql, group-by

I would like to know how to get the amounts paid for the last two months paid per city ordered per year.

If I group by year, city name and two months :

```
select year, nameCity, twoMonths, payment
From t
group by year, nameCity, twoMonths
```

I would have something like this :

```
2018 :  city1 :  2   200
                 4   300
                 6   400

        city2 :  2   250
                 4   100


2019 :  city1 :  1   100
                 2   200
                 3   500

        city2 :  2   750
                 4   180
                 6   220
```

But the output I want is something like this:

```
2018    city1   6   400 
        city2   4   100

2019   city1    3   500 
       city2    6   220
```

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Please tag your question with the RDBMS that you are using: oracle, sql-server, postgresql...?

Comment: Do you really have a column called `twoMonths` in your table?

Comment: Also, your expected output data does not seem to completely agree with the inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a subquery to find the most values of `twoMonths` for each year and city, and the join to it:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT year, nameCity, MAX(twoMonths) AS maxTwoMonths
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY year, nameCity
) t2
    ON t1.year = t2.year AND
       t1.nameCity = t2.nameCity AND
       t1.twoMonths = t2.maxTwoMonths
```

If your version of SQL support `ROW_NUMBER`, then it can provide an alternative:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY year, nameCity
                                 ORDER BY twoMonths DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT year, nameCity, twoMonths, payment
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT year,nameCity,MAX(twoMonths),MAX(payment)
GROUP BY year,nameCity
```